# cakephp sql find all fields

Tags: sql, cakephp, request, find, cakephp-2.0

My request is:

```
$monits = $this->Monit->find('all',  array('recursive'=>'0'));
```

The result is:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Monit' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'nom' => 'mon'
            'ecole_id' => '1'
        ),
        'Ecole' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'nom' => 'ecole name'
        ),
        'Seance' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'title' => 'ele name',
                'monit_id' => '1'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'title' => 'ele name',
                'monit_id' => '1'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I would like select only 'Monit and Ecole' and eliminate 'Seance'. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

It's also good practice to set `public $recursive = -1;` in your AppModel.  This will default the recursive level to `-1` for all your models and is good to do because using recursive is basically considered bad practice since the introduction of Containable.

"recursive" was a novel idea, and has some merit when doing simple apps like a blog...etc, but it's been abandoned and even removed from Cake 3 simply because of how awesome (and easy to use) the Containable Behavior is.  There is no reason to ever get more data than you actually need, and recursive does exactly that.  Containable, on the other hand, lets you specify EXACTLY what associated data you'd like.

Comment: i try: 
$monits= $this->Monit->recursive = -1;
$monits= $this->Monit->find('all', array('contain' => 'Ecole.nom'));
and the result like
$monits= $this->Monit->recursive = -1;